# const char * testing equality with a character

Tags: c++

I would like to return "jackpot" if there is only one character in "toParse" and the character is either "+" or "0". What is the most elegant way to do this? I tried this but apparently it does not work as it returns "jackpot" all the time for unknown reason.

```
char* ParseNRZI::parse(const char* toParse){
    if (toParse=="+"||toParse=="0")
        return "jackpot";
}
```

Comment: You don't have a second `return` statement...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `strcmp` if you compare C style pointers to char

```
char* ParseNRZI::parse(const char* toParse)
{
    if (strcmp(toParse, "+") == 0 ||
        strcmp(toParse, "0") == 0)
    {
        return "jackpot";
    }
    return "something else";
}
```

Or if you use `std::string` you can use `operator==` freely

```
std::string ParseNRZI::parse(const std::string& toParse)
{
    if (toParse == "+" || 
        toParse == "0") 
    {
        return std::string("jackpot");
    }
    return std::string("something else");
}
```

For design point of view, you are wring a check function not a real parsing function. Then you can rewrite your function to:

```
bool isJackpot(const std::string& value) 
{
    if (toParse == "+" || 
        toParse == "0") 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and it can simplified to:

```
bool isJackpot(const std::string& value) 
{
  return value.find_first_of("0+") != std::string::npos;
}
```

Note: your function doesn't always return `char*` in all branches it will invoke undefined behavior when `toParse` is not `+` or `0`. Make sure all your function branches return a value when function return type is not `void`.

Comment: So the reason it returns "jackpot" in the other cases (when it is not + nor 0) is an undefined behaviour?

Comment: There is one more problem. If I return "" then it is of type const char*. However, the return type is char* (and I am not allowed to change it).

Comment: `"jackpot"` is also const char *, it's string literal

Comment: That is the problem. It can not be "const char*". It should be "char*" because that is the return type.

Comment: It's not great design. your function doesn't do "parse", more like check... I'd like to write it this way: `bool isJackpot(const char* toParse) { return false;} `

Comment: I just found the solution. I should do "return const_cast<char*>("jackpot")". This way it does not show any warning anymore (although it is kindof nasty solution)

Comment: If you can make sure you don't change the returned string.... otherwise no good. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    const char* ParseNRZI::parse(const char* toParse) const
    {
      if (( toParse != 0 ) &&
          ( toParse[0] == '+' || toParse[0] == '0' ) &&
          ( toParse[1] == 0 )
         )
        return "jackpot";

      return "";

    }
```

Comment: What if I cannot change the return type to const char*? I know it only issues a warning but my program must not generate any warning.

Comment: @Slazer - if you return a string literal from a function that returns `char*` you are throwing away const correctness. Sooner or later you'll pass that pointer to a function that modifies its target string, and your code will mysteriously blow up. Don't fix warnings by hacking around them. Understand what they mean and why they're there, and if the warning is telling you something useful (as it would be here), then take the advice and don't do what you're trying to do. "I'm not allowed to change the return type" is not a valid reason for writing broken code.